# Homemorphic problem between circle and torus: how to write up the proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

Source:A first course on topology. Robert Conover

Ex 6,pg 90

**Problem**

Let $S^1$ denote the unit circle as subspace of the Euclidean plane. Let T denote the (hollow)torus as subspace  of 3-space with product topology that gets by
virtue of being
R$\times$ R $\times$ R
(Where each copy or R has its usual topology)

Let $S^1 \times S^1$ have the product topology and show that $S^1 \times S^1$ and T are homeomorphic

**What I know**
Here is a possible analytic def of T and some ideas I found
on how to do it.

[http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/tg/html/topsp07.html](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahjde/tg/html/topsp07.html)

I know how to do homeomorphic problems
when simple,but this one baffles me.

Procedure is:

1.show it is bijection

2.Continuous

3.inverse exists

I can say $S^1 \times S^1$ are 2 closed circles and  is continuous within the subspace of the  torus. I don’t know how to show the math for it. There does not seem any neat way to do
a bijection between a sphere and a torus that I can find.

Any help in showing the proof would be appreciated

Comment: $S^2$ is a sphere. $S^1 \times S^1$ is not a sphere.

Comment: You'll need an *analytic* definition of $T$ in order to do this problem, i.e. formulas or equations which specify it . Without that, your problem doesn't make much sense; the words you wrote to describe $T$ are nice and intuitive, but cannot be used to solve this problem by themselves.

Comment: Here is the page for formula of a torus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus would any of these help?@Lee Mosher. I think Conover is leaving that part up to the student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $T$ is presumably given as a [surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution) with a circle as the generatrix and a suitable axis of rotation. This description will immediately give the map you are looking for from $S^1 \times S^1$ to $T$. To prove that it is a homeomorphism, show that it is bijective and continuous and observe that an bijective continuous mapping between two compact hausdorff spaces is closed and hence its inverse is continuous.

Comment: Holy crap I looked at that page, it looks like differential geometry.

Comment: Your don't need to use the fact that the map is differentiable, just that it is injective and continuous.

Comment: http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/tg/html/topsp07.html ,would this be useful for formula and doing the proof @Rob Arthan

Comment: That link looks good. If you can't use compactness, then you can prove that the inverse is continuous from first principles.

Comment: In the URL l gave they say the map is bijective, how can we make cos and sin bijection. Restrict its range?